# How to implement "Are you sure you want to submit the form again" in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

In Safari, a warning is displayed when trying to reload the form, whereas WKWebView does not display warnings when reload.

How can I implement "Are you sure you want to submit the form again"?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement **WKNavigationDelegate#webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)**.

Then, if **navigationAction.navigationType** is **formResubmitted**, show alert.

For alert's submit or cancel button action, call **decisionHandler(.allow)** or **decisionHandler(.cancel)**, respectively.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if case .formResubmitted = navigationAction.navigationType {
        // Show alert   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add an alert creating an UIAlertController and then add custom actions to it.

For an example in your case:

```
//Create the alert using UIAlertController. Add your custom title and custom message
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Information", message: "Are you sure you want to submit the form again", preferredStyle: .alert)

//Add custom buttons with different style
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

//Present the alertView
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You can make this as a function and then you can call it whenever you refresh the page.

Comment: Thank you! And I 'd like to know when I'm trying to reload a sent form.

Comment: You could make a function that whenever a user is for example pressing the "reload-button" the webView is being reloaded and you show the alert message. You can simply call the the reload the webView from your webView outlet like "webView.reload()" and beneath that line of code, you can add the alert function I wrote above.

Comment: I 'd like to know if the user is about to reload the form or other. This alert prevents double transmission of Form.